# If $S= \overline {abc}_j$ and $S = \overline{cba}_{j+1}$ with $a, c \neq 0,$ find $S$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $j\ge 3$ is a positive integer, and $S= \overline {abc}_j$ and $S = \overline{cba}_{j+1}$ with $a, c \neq 0,$ find all possible $S$.

---

My progress:
I set up the equation
$$aj^2+bj+c = c(j+1)^2+b(j+1) + a,$$
and simplified it into
$$a(j^2-1) = c(j^2+2j)+b.$$
But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help?

EDIT: It seems as though they only exist for odd $j$ and are of the form $a=\lceil j/2\rceil, b = c =a-1,$ in base $j$. How can I prove these are the only ones? Or, are they even the only ones?

Comment: What is your $g$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $j$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you should write it as a quadratic equation as follows:

$$aj^2+bj+c=c(j+1)^2+b(j+1)+a=cj^2+2cj+c+bj+b+a$$
$$(a-c)j^2-2cj-(b+a)=0$$

Suppose $j^*$ is a positive integer solution to the equation above. By considering the expansion of $(mj+n)(j-j^*)$ (with $m,n \ge 0$), we see that $j^* \mid (b+a)$.

However we must have $0 \le a,b < j^*$. This forces $a+b = j^*$. We now have

$$(a-c){j^*}^2-2cj^*-j^*=j^*((a-c)j^*-2c-1)=0$$

This implies $j^* = \dfrac {2c+1}{a-c}$. Suppose $a-c > 1$. $a-c \ne 2$ since $j^*$ is an integer.

This gives $a-c \ge 3$, and we will have $j^* \le \dfrac {2c+1}3\le \dfrac {2c+c}3=c$, which is a contradiction.

Hence $a-c = 1$ and $a+b = j^* = 2c+1$. (Here it is more obvious that $j^*$ is odd.)

Solving the equations in terms of $j^*$, we have

$$a = \frac {j^*+1}2, b = c = a-1 = \frac {j^*-1}2$$

and finally we check the result for any odd $j^* \ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you so much!  What motivated you to write the quadratic in that form?

Comment: Since we assumed that $j^*$ is a root of our quadratic equation, it must contain the factor $(j-j^*)$. The general result for polynomials is the Rational Root Theorem.

Comment: $(a-c)(j^*)^2-2c(j^*)-(b+a)=0 \Rightarrow j^* | (b+a).$

Comment: Or killing two birds with one stone:
$2j^* > a+b=j^*((a-c)j^*-2c) \Rightarrow j^*=a+b, (a-c)j^*-2c=1$. Anyway, nice proof!